# How to fix Base table or view not found database table using laravel

Tags: laravel

I have common error and I don't know what I called on this problem. so please I will let explain to you the problem that I encounter.

So right now i'am using laravel 5.7 and I did multiple auth guard. so right now I have login for salesperson so I created migration table for all sales person users. so I already migrated **2020_05_16_190202_create_salesperson_table.php** successfully created to the database.

Lets move to the error that I encounter after I login, note that I have sales_person table.
after I click the submit button I have error and the error is Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.sales_people' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sales_people` where `email` = example@gmail.com limit 1)

so why is it my App/Salesperson looking for sales_people? I have no sales_people table on my database. I only have sales_person. So I really don't understand why this error gives me.

**Problem:** Why is it my App/Salesperson looking for sales_people table which is not created to the migration?

**Model:**

```
   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class SalesPerson extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'salesperson';

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 
        'middle_name', 
        'last_name', 
        'email', 
        'password', 
        'mothers_maiden_name', 
        'emergency_contact',
        'emergency_contact_num',
        'address',
        'tin_num',
        'valid_photo',
        'parent_id',
        'created_at'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**Migration:**

```
   <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSalespersonTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('salesperson', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('middle_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('mothers_maiden_name');
            $table->string('emergency_contact');
            $table->string('emergency_contact_num');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('tin_num');
            $table->string('valid_photo');
            $table->enum('member_status', array('Active','Pending'))->default('Pending');
            $table->string('parent_id');
            $table->string('sponsor_id');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('salesperson');
    }
}
```

**DB Table:**

[image: Table]

Comment: Because of the model's name SalesPerson

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ can you explain more please.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

**Table Names**

Note that we did not tell Eloquent which table to use for our `SalesPerson` model. By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the `SalesPerson` model stores records in the `sales_persons` table. You may specify a custom table by defining a table property on your model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class SalesPerson extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'salesperson';

    // ... everything else you already have
}
```

You could also change the name of the table to follow the conventions, that way you won't have to make it explicit in the model:

```
Schema::create('sales_persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1377

Laravel creates a tablename using:

```php
return $this->table ?? Str::snake(Str::pluralStudly(class_basename($this)));
```

Because you have not provided a name, it is created.

You should force the name in your modal using:

```php
class SalesPerson extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'salesperson';

    // the rest
}
```

Comment: so do you mean for that is I need to change the $guard variable to $table?

Comment: What do you think the `$guard` is for?

Comment: I'm using for multiple auth guard.  if (Auth::guard('salesperson')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

     
        }

Comment: That is not a problem, this is the `SalesPerson` class, so it's table should always be `salesperson`, right? So you should probably have both.

Comment: yah your correct. I refresh my migration and I do protected $table = 'salesperson'; and now it works.